# Facebook - Object Debugger - Error Parsing URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

For this URL I am getting the following message from the lint tool -

Error Parsing URL   Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

URL...
http://apps.facebook.com/mischiefshoes/?entry_id=201012

Full link to Canvas frame...
https://www.mischiefshoes.co.nz/facebook/competition/?entry_id=201012

When going to post a open graph action this error is logged...

OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL http://apps.facebook.com/mischiefshoes/?entry_id=201012 has og:type of 'website'. The property 'shoe' requires an object of og:type 'mischiefshoes:shoe'.

Yet my og meta tags are as follows:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Michael R. J. Crosbie's favourite shoe"/> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Michael R. J. Crosbie's favourite shoe in the mischief shoes instashoe competition. Win $2000 worth of shoes every month - upload your own today!"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.mischiefshoes.co.nz/media/client/resources/instashoe/201012/237x_scale/Ciara_Misfits.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="MISCHIEF SHOES • WIN FREE SHOES"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="256092351106970"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="mischiefshoes:shoe" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers, Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a response time issue. When I take a look at your page in Chrome or using a [third party speed test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/Nq1mNrUxp/https://www.mischiefshoes.co.nz/facebook/competition/?entry_id=201012) I have to wait over 11 seconds for your server to respond.

Facebook's servers are probably timing out before your server responds.

Comment: Seemed to do the trick. What was taking the time was making API calls to facebook. Ironic?